# query parameters in url doesn't work in laravel json response?

Tags: json, laravel, postman

let's just I have returned this json as response from Laravel:

```
Route::get('/data', function(){

    $drivers = Driver::select('driver_number','first_name','ph_number')
                ->where('driver_number',$request->get('driver_number'))
                ->get();

    return response()->json($drivers);
});
```

the above returns this json:

```
[
{
    "driver_number": "Dr_01",
    "first_name": "jimale",
    "ph_number": 4253226
},
{
    "driver_number": "Dr_02",
    "first_name": "mawlid",
    "ph_number": 4222321
},
{
    "driver_number": "Dr_03",
    "first_name": "yusuf",
    "ph_number": 3624222
},
{
    "driver_number": "Dr_04",
    "first_name": "yaxye",
    "ph_number": 343243
}
]
```

So, I wanted to receive a single json object where `driver_number`= `Dr_02`... for that reason i used **POSTMAN** to do that and i said like this:

> http://localhost/BSProject/public/data?driver_number=Dr_02

BUT this is displaying all JSON Array instead of my specific json object.
Do any one knows where i missed? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write your filter query with where clause like this :

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $drivers = Driver::select('driver_number','first_name','ph_number')->where('driver_number',$request->get('driver_number'))->get();
}
```

Comment: where does that request is coming from, i dont have it in my  code

Comment: thanks dude, that's my bad didn't notice sending request to get the target json

Comment: @AhmedAtoui,@MaiRich
The actual problem was the dependency injection
`Route::get('/data', function(Request $request)`

$request is undefined in the first example! You meant to use request(), the global helper function :)